# JSP page in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new developing a web app using spring and jsp. Currently I have one jsp file i.e index.jsp. Now i want to create one more .jsp file and link them. I have created jsp file and added the code.

But while running , the second file is throwing error that, resource for second file not found. I am just confused whether I need to add any controller information for the second file?

My code:

```
<a href="<c:url value="content.jsp"/>">
     <li style="background-color: #3f91bd;"><%=rs2.getString("FORM_NAME")%></li>
</a>
```

Can any one tell me about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the location of content.jsp?

Comment: check the url when you hover the mouse on your content.jsp link from index.jsp file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using a `spring-mvc` then you don't call `jsp page` directly.
You have to map jsp in controller request mapping. See example

**fisrt mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login() {
    return "index";
}
```

**second mapping**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/other-page-link", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String linkpage() {
    return "other-jsp";
}
```

you have to jsp page i.e. `index.jsp` and `other-jsp`

```
<a href="<c:url value="/other-page-link"/>">
    <li style="background-color: #3f91bd;"><%=rs2.getString("FORM_NAME")%></li>
</a>
```

Hope my explanation is work for you if you have any doubt then we can discuss.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how could I access js and css files. I have checked online. But asking o add entry in Dispatcher_servlet.xml which thows eror. Is there any way to add in my controller.java file itself?

Comment: am not able to understand can u elaborate @safoora safu

Comment: I did this using <spring:url> tag.